# Assigning list to GridViewData in Windows Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm facing a strange issue where I'm assigning a `List` of `Strings` to a `GridViewData` but instead of showing me the list of string, `GridViewData` is showing numbers.

Code is as following:

```
private void ShowListofObjects()
{
    dgvShowObjects.DataSource = showObjects(dtMenu, dtAllActiveUsersAccessRights);
}

private List<string> showObjects(DataTable dtMenu, DataTable dtAllActiveUsersAccessRights)
{
    DataTable dtFinalTable = new DataTable();
    dtFinalTable.Columns.Add("Object", typeof(String));
    dtFinalTable.Columns.Add("Add", typeof(String));
    dtFinalTable.Columns.Add("View", typeof(String));
    dtFinalTable.Columns.Add("Modify", typeof(String));
    List<string> l = new List<string>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dtMenu.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string obj = dtMenu.Rows[i][1].ToString(); // first item in Menu Table
        for (int j = 0; j < dtAllActiveUsersAccessRights.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            string s = dtAllActiveUsersAccessRights.Rows[j][1].ToString();
            if (s == obj)
            {
                l.Add(dtAllActiveUsersAccessRights.Rows[j][1].ToString());
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    lblCounter.Text = counter.ToString();
    return l;
}
```

On debugging, on line `return l;` I can see List `l` populated with string values but when I'm assigning this list to GridViewData on line `dgvShowObjects.DataSource = showObjects(dtMenu, dtAllActiveUsersAccessRights);` and run the application, its showing a list of numbers.

Can anyone see why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you determine if the underlying data source of displayed cell, for example 5, is string or numeric value?

Comment: @IvayloPetrov While dubugging as I move mouse cursor on line `dgvShowObjects.DataSource = showObjects(dtMenu, dtAllActiveUsersAccessRights);`'s DataSource part, its showing a list of strings. Same list that I need to display on the gridview. But a list of number is rather being displayed on the gridViewData.